# What are different types of Backend Services in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I want to attach a Security Policy from Google Cloud Armor to my backend services. On the basic level, anything that is exposed to the traffic outside warrants some protection, and in this case, it warrants an attachment of a Security Policy.

However, the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#https-load-balancer) states `gcloud compute backend-services list` and often creates them using `gcloud compute backend-services create <name>`. In the codebase that I am working on, I am not able to see how those 4 services are created.

I have multiple `kind: Deployment`.

Does declaring a load balancer create a service?

When I run the command `backend-services list`, I get these:

```
k8s-be-30443--0488034603124a19
```

These are different from the `kind: Deployment` I have as the names don't match.

Moreover, there is a load-balancer configuration that has a `kind: BackendConfig` along with and the API version is `apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1`.

And when I had attached a Security Policy to one, APIs were failed.

Comment: So you are using GKE, have Deployments which are exposed via Ingress and you want to attach Cloud Armor security policies?  Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#cloud_armor